# Smoothing path of a robot

Tags: geometry, robotics

I'm calculating shortest path of a robot on a plane with polygonal obstacles. Everything works well and fast, no problems there. But, how to smoothen the path so it becomes curvy ?
Below is a picture of a path connecting vertices with a straight line. 
P.S
Robot is just a circle.

[image: Vertices]

Comment: First step: you need to define the turning radius of your robot.  If it can turn on a dime efficiently, why would you *want* it to take a curvy path?

Comment: You're right. I knew somebody would ask me that. My robot will have a full turning radius but I wanted to find out how is it done, even so. "How to connect points with a curve" was meant to be the real question. I apologize.

Comment: I do think that that number is intrinsic to answering the question though.  But we can use some variable I suppose, say `TR` to represent the turning radius. In that case, you've already answered your own question for the special case of `TR=0`.

Comment: @iccthedral I am interested in how you did the pathfinding, how did you do it? What algorithm?

Comment: @Murplyx I've used Minkowski sum algorithm. Google these keywords  minkowski+motion+planing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CCwQFjAD&url=http://www.mgvis.com/Papers/Geometry/Short_smooth_paths.pdf&rct=j&q=smooth%20polygonal%20path&ei=WnCbTdPrLcS60QHL2J3nAg&usg=AFQjCNFp8q-YsaasJjP60bmvjpIZ4YAY-w&sig2=Pw9j4gSmInVdsn5Mtw-vcw&cad=rja) might be useful.  It looks like it's a non-trivial problem.  Abstract:

> Automatic graph drawers need to compute paths among ver- tices of a simple polygon which besides remaining in the interior need to exhibit certain aesthetic properties. Some of these require the incorpo- ration of some information about the polygonal shape without being too far from the actual shortest path. We present an algorithm to compute a locally convex region that “contains” the shortest Euclidean path among two vertices of a simple polygon. The region has a boundary shape that “follows” the shortest path shape. A cubic Bezier spline in the region in- terior provides a “short and smooth” collision free curve between the two given vertices. The obtained results appear to be aesthetically pleasant and the methods used may be of independent interest. They are elemen- tary and implementable. Figure 7 is a sample output produced by our current implementation.

Answer (score 5):

I used to play with path calculation techniques a lot when trying to make realistic flying sequences to be rendered in [Teragen](http://www.planetside.co.uk/). I initially tried using [Bézier Curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

[image: Curves]

But discovered that (for flying at least) they aren't that useful. The reason is that the curvature between curves is discontinuous, and so cannot be used to calculate a continuous correct banking angle for a fly-by. Also, it's hard to be sure that the curve doesn't intersect an mountain.

I digress. The way I eventually settled on was a simple mass-spring based path, and relax it into submission.

Subdivide the path into lots of little segments, the more the merrier. For each point, move it a little bit in a direction so as to reduce the angle between it and its neighbours, and way from the obstacles. Repeat many times until the path has settled down.

```
k = 0.01    // Adjust the values of k and j to your liking.
j = 0.01    // Small values take longer to settle. Larger values are unstable.
For each point P
    normal_vector     = vector_to_previous_point + vector_to_next_point
    obstacle_vector   = vector_to_nearest_obstacle
    obstacle_distance = magnitude(obstacle_vector)
    obstacle_vector  *= obstacle_distance^2
    P                += (normal_vector * k) - (obstacle_vector * j)
```

The benefit of these kind of finite element relaxation techniques is that you can program all kinds of constraints into it, and the path will settle on some compromise between them, depending on the weights (j and k in this case).

---

If you're into robotics, why not come and join the [Robotics Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40020)?

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just make the path curvy in the actual execution of the path following algorithm?  If you leave the path as is (i.e. connected straight lines), implementing a look ahead distance of ~1 meter (this value will depend on the speed of your robot and the amount you've padded the configuration space to avoid obstacles) in the control algorithm that calculates the velocity of each wheel will automatically smooth out the path without any need for preprocessing.

Here's a quick images of what I mean...the red dotted-line is the path that is actually executed by the robot when you control to a point based on a lookahead distance. A lookahead distance just computes a point further down the path by some arbitrary distance.

[image]

Again, the only thing you have to worry about is how much you're padding obstacles to make sure you avoid hitting them. Normally I believe the area of an obstacle is padded by half the robot's radius, but if you're controlling to a lookahead distance you may have to make this slightly larger.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a robot we can't know the future.  We have to draw each point knowing only the location of the robot and the obstacles.  The usual method for making curved paths of minimum length is to model the robot with a circle and move the circle so it remains in contact with the obstacles.  Just keep one radius away and the turns will be curves.

If you want curves and NOT minimum distance try making the above radius proportional to the distance you are from a polygon vertex.

The Bezier curves idea only works to make the path curved in retrospect.  It changes where the robot ha been.  Usually with robots changing the past is called "cheating".   One way to avoid having to change the path you've already walked is to look ahead.  But can the robot see around corners?  You have to specify the rules better.